# Android: Is it possible to disassemble an obb file

Tags: android, apk, decompiling

I would like to know if it is possible for users to decompile/disassemble my app's OBB files as they can do with APK files, and if so, if there is a way to block them from doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OBB files are conventionally just zip files. Try unzipping yours.